# Echoing a string in bash with brackets surrounding it returns 'b'

Tags: bash

```
$ a='"apple","ball","cat"'
$ a='['$a
$ echo $a
["apple","ball","cat"
$ a=$a']'
$ echo $a
b
```

I'm stumped hard by the result `b` while I expect to see `["apple,"ball","cat"]`. What am I missing here?

This is from `bash` shell on Mac. Also see it on CentOS 7, while not on Fedora. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Some of your lines begin with a dollar sign ($). Is that the Bash prompt or are you typing that in?

Comment: I'm assuming the dollar signs are Bash prompts, in which case I am not able to reproduce the behavior you've described.

Comment: What do you get if you run it under `set -xv`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that is indeed the bash prompt.

Comment: @choroba, this is what I see   a=[$a]
a=[$a]  
+ a='["apple","ball","cat"]'   but when I do    echo $a  
+ echo b  
b

Comment: Don't you set $a in your $PROMPT_COMMAND or $PS1?

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Can't reproduce with `GNU bash, version 4.3.48`, I get the expected `["apple","ball","cat"]`.

Answer (score 27):

There is a file with the name `b` in the current directory.

```
[...]
```

is a pattern matching expression. It matches every file of which the name consists of a single letter between `[` and `]`.

This is similar to having `*` in a variable value and using the variable without quotes.

Comment: +1 Good catch. The corollary here is, I suppose, that variables should be quoted when used (`echo "$a"` writes the literal value of `$a`).

Comment: For loads more information about that: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Answer (score 3):

Hauke already answered why it's happening. For future reference, you can also troubleshoot what is happening with `strace`:

```
$ touch a b l
$ a='["apple","ball"]'                                                      
$ strace -e trace=execve echo $a
execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "a", "b", "l"], [/* 82 vars */]) = 0
a b l
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Or with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x; echo $a
+ set -x
+ echo a b l
a b l
```

It's  might not immediately be clear, but at least you see that shell has converted the unquoted variable into a list of items; from there we can deduce that filename expansion occurred.